# $\mathbb{B}^n$ has the fixed point property $\implies \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{B}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I'm struggling to understand the proof of this theorem.

> **Theorem:** $\mathbb{B}^n$ has the fixed point property $\implies \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is not a retract of $\mathbb{B}^n$
>
> **Proof:** Let's suppose there exists a rectraction $r:\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Then the function $f:\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{B}^{n-1}$ given by $f(x)=-r(x)$ is a continuous function. $\mathbb{B}^n$ has the fixed point property, so there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{B}^2$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$. But $r(x_0) \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, so $x_0 = -r(x_0) \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. $r$ is a rectraction, so $r(x_0)=x_0=-r(x_0)$, which is a cotradiction, because  $r(x_0)\in  \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

I don't understand how $f(x_0)=x_0$, because $x_0 \in  \mathbb{B}^{2}$ and  $f(x_0) \in \mathbb{B}^{1}= \{x: x\in [-1,1]\}$, so to me the equality would only make sense if the fixed point of  $\mathbb{B}^{2}$ happened to be in the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{B}^{2}: y=0\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this proof has a couple of mistakes.

First of all, you'd want $f:\Bbb B^n\to \Bbb B^n$. Because $\Bbb S^{n-1}\subseteq \Bbb B^n$, not $\Bbb B^{n-1}$. Also, how would the fixed point property ever enter into this if $f$ didn't have the same domain as codomain?

Second, why $\Bbb B^2$ all of a sudden?

Here is the proof with those two errors corrected:

> **Proof:** Let's suppose there exists a rectraction $r:\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Then the function $f:\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{B}^{n}$ given by $f(x)=-r(x)$ is a continuous function. $\mathbb{B}^n$ has the fixed point property, so there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{B}^n$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$. But $r(x_0) \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, so $x_0 = -r(x_0) \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. $r$ is a rectraction, so $r(x_0)=x_0=-r(x_0)$, which is a cotradiction, because  $r(x_0)\in  \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

Now, as for your question (maybe the corrections have made it clearer already): $f$ is a continuous function from $\Bbb B^n$ to $\Bbb B^n$, and $\Bbb B^n$ has the fixed-point property. "The fixed-point-property" means that any continuous function from that space to itself has a fixed point. A fixed point is a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. As to why the author took $\mathbb{B}^2$ all of a sudden, it is because he used this result to prove $\mathbb{B}^2$ has the fixed point property by using that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not contractible, and we haven't proved yet the non contractibility of  $\mathbb{S}^n$ for $n \gt 1$, but it's nice to see that this result holds for general $n$.

Comment: @Yagger When they state a general theorem like that, and start the proof off general, suddenly specialising it to $n = 2$ seems off to me. Regardless of what they have done earlier on that page, or what they plan on using it for further down.

Comment: Yeah, it made me confused at first because I couldn't see the reason why it wouldn't hold for $n \gt 2$.

Comment: @Yagger Do You say the author wants to conclude" $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not contractible and thus $\mathbb{B}^2$ has the fixed point property". Wouldn't that require the reverse conclusion to the theorem he tried to prove?

Comment: @PeterMelech The theorem included the converse, but I only included the direction whose proof I didn't understand.

Comment: @Yagger Ah ok. Thanks